# How can I apply this macro to all the pages in an excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have a code to do a particular modification to some cells in a page. I'd like to apply this code at one click to all the pages in the excel file. I'm using VBA and am a newbie to it. Here's my code :

`Sub H()
    Dim B As Range, H As Range, I As Range
    For Each B In Range("B7:B49").Cells
        If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
            Cells(B.Row, 9) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 8)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 8))
            Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) = ""
            Cells(B.Row + 2, 8) = ""
        If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For
    End If
    Next B
End Sub`

I'd like to apply the above macro to all the pages in the excel sheet. How can I do that?

Comment: Hello again.  Why do you declare `H` and `I` and then not use them?  Why do you declare a Range with the same name as the subroutine?

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the sheets (pages)
the same way you loop through the cells in a range:

```
Sub H()
    Dim B As Range

    For S in Sheets
        For Each B In S.Range("B7:B49").Cells
            If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
                Cells(B.Row, 9) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 8)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 8))
                Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) = ""
                Cells(B.Row + 2, 8) = ""
            End If
            If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For
        Next B
    Next S

End Sub
```

P.S. It probably makes more sense to have the two `If` statements independent;
i.e., not have the second one nested inside the first.